# KeyError: ('1', 'occurred at index 0')

Tags: python, dataframe, apply, axis, keyerror

I really new working with python and I'm working with the following dataframes:

```py
    data1 = {'Store_ID':['1','1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3'],
             'YearMonth':[201801,201802,201805,201904,201812,201902,201906,201904,201907],
             'AVG_Rating':[5.0,4.5,4.0,3.5,3.0,4.5,4.0,2.5,4.0]}

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

```
--------------------AVG_Rating
Store_ID    AnoMes  
1           201801  5.0
            201802  4.5
            201805  4.0
            201904  3.5
2           201812  3.0
            201902  4.5
            201906  4.0
3           201904  2.5
            201907  4.0
```

```py
    data2 = {'Client_ID':['1212','1234','1122','1230'],
             'Store_ID':['1','1','2','3'],
             'YearMonth':[201804,201906,201904,201906]}
```

```
------------Client_ID---YearMonth
Store_ID        
1           1212        201804
1           1234        201906
2           1122        201904
3           1230        201906
```

I set index to two DFs by Store_ID column.

I have to merge both bringing the most recent AVG_Rating from DF1 based on column YearMonth that it is the year month that client make a purchase in a store. My final data frame has to be:

-------Client_ID----YearMonth-----AVG_Rating
Store_ID
1           1212    201804        4.5 (Rating in 201802)

For that i'm trying to use function below more apply function but it occurs an error:

```py
    def get_previous_loja_rating(row):
        loja = df1[row['Loja_ID']]
        lst = loja[loja['AnoMes']] < df2[row['AnoMes']]
        return lst[-1]

    df2['PREVIOUS_RATING_MEAN'] = df1['AnoMes'].apply(get_previous_loja_rating,axis=1)
```

> KeyError: ('Loja_ID', 'occurred at index 1')

Could please someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be using YearMonth as the column name instead of AnoMes. There are multiple reasons why your code function is failing.
From what I understood, you would like a avg rating column to be added with the values of the most recent yearmonth of the corresponding store.

```py
df1
Store_ID    YearMonth   AVG_Rating
0   1   201801  5.0
1   1   201802  4.5
2   1   201805  4.0
3   1   201904  3.5
4   2   201812  3.0
df2
Client_ID   Store_ID    YearMonth
0   1212    1   201804
1   1234    1   201906
2   1122    2   201904
3   1230    3   201906


def get_previous_loja_rating(row):
    loja = df1[df1['Store_ID']==row['Store_ID']]
    lst = [i for i in loja['YearMonth'] if i <= row['YearMonth']] #list of all yearmonth values less than or equal to client's yearmonth
    return df1[(df1['YearMonth']==max(lst))&(df1['Store_ID']==row['Store_ID'])]['AVG_Rating'].iloc[0] # avg rating of the most recent yearmonth

df2['AVG_Rating'] = df2.apply(get_previous_loja_rating,axis=1)

df2
Client_ID   Store_ID    YearMonth   AVG_Rating
0   1212    1   201804  4.5
1   1234    1   201906  3.5
2   1122    2   201904  4.5
3   1230    3   201906  2.5
```

This would give the closest yearmonth's avg rating into your client dataframe

Comment: @FernandoRodriguesNepomuceno If it is the desired result, please mark this as answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to use Spanish key names (`Loja_ID`, `AnoMes`, etc.) in your code, while your data uses English. You are going to want to change these to `Client_ID` and `YearMonth`.